# HWIOAuthBundle + FOSUserBundle integration doesn't work

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I have a project with FOSUserBundle. And need to add an OAuth support. So I installed HWIOAuthBundle and configured like said here https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697 and here https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/bonus/facebook-connect.md But when i'am trying to login it returns me Bad credentials. What am I doing wrong?

My security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:      /security/check-facebook
                login_path:        /security
                use_forward:       false
                failure_path:      /security
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my_user_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false
            remember_me:
                key: "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000
                path: /
                domain: ~
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/redirect.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/security.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/connect.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /redirect

hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /security

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /connect

facebook_login:
    pattern: /security/check-facebook
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: test_chat_user_registration

hwi_oauth:
    connect:
        account_connector: my_user_provider
    firewall_name: main
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            facebook: facebookId
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           "%facebook_id%"
            client_secret:       "%facebook_access_token%%"
            scope:               "email"
            options:
                display: popup
```

services.yml

```
parameters:
    my_user_provider.class: AppBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider

services:
    my_user_provider:
        class: "%my_user_provider.class%"
        arguments: [@fos_user.user_manager,{facebook: facebookId}]
```

user provider

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security\Core\User;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseUserProvider;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface as FOSUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * AppBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider
 *
 * @author Ivan Molchanov <ivan.molchanov@opensoftdev.ru>
 */
class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseUserProvider
{
    /**
     * @param UserInterface         $user
     * @param UserResponseInterface $response
     * @return void
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        /** @var User $previousUser */
        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy([$property => $username])) {
            $previousUser->setFacebookId(null);
            $previousUser->setFacebookAccessToken(null);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }
        /** @var User $user */
        $user->setFacebookId($username);
        $user->setFacebookAccessToken($response->getAccessToken());
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * @param UserResponseInterface $response
     * @return FOSUserInterface
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        $user =    $this->userManager->findUserBy([$this->getProperty($response) => $username]);
        if (null === $user) {
            $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
            $user->setFacebookId($username);
            $user->setFacebookAccessToken($response->getAccessToken());
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setEmail($username);
            $user->setPassword($username);
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

            return $user;
        }
        $user = parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);
        $user->setFacebookAccessToken($response->getAccessToken());

        return $user;
    }
}
```

login.html.twig

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {% if error %}
                <div class="errors">{{ error|trans }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="_password"/>
                        <a href="{{ path("fos_user_resetting_check_email") }}">{% trans %}Reset password{% endtrans %}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked/>
                                {{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                        <button type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" class="btn btn-success">
                            <i class="icon ion-log-in"></i>
                            {{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary facebook-login-button">
                            <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
                            {% trans %}Log in via Facebook{% endtrans %}
                        </button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 registration">
            {% trans %}If you don't have an account you could create it here:{% endtrans %}
            <br/>
            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                {% trans %}Registration{% endtrans %}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    {% render(controller('HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect')) %}
{% endblock content %}

{% block foot_script %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" id="facebook-jssdk" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        //init facebook
        window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
        {
            FB.init(
                {
                    appId: '{{ facebook_id }}',
                    status: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    cookie: true,
                    version: 'v2.3'
                }
            );
        };

        $('.facebook-login-button').on(
            'click', function ()
            {
                FB.getLoginStatus(
                    function (response)
                    {
                        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                            document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}";
                        } else {
                            FB.login(
                                function (response)
                                {
                                    if (response.authResponse) {
                                        document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}";
                                    } else {
                                        alert('Cancelled.');
                                    }
                                }, {scope: 'email'}
                            );
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
{% endblock foot_script %}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, do you find something?

Comment: How do you login? Using the login form we've seen or the facebook integration?